# translate apache2 rewrite rules

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

i have this file .htaccess for apache :

```
# we check if the .html version is here (caching)
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# no, so we redirect to our front web controller
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

how can i convert this to .htaccess for nginx ?

i tryed with this :

```
  location / {
    rewrite ^/$ /index.html;
    rewrite / /RewriteRule;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php last;
  }
```

you think correct ?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need rewrites for such things, just the [try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files).

```
try_files /index.html$is_args$args $uri.html$is_args$args $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
```